# Intercept all NFC tags on Android

Tags: android, nfc

I am currently trying to intercept all NFC communication on an Android Device. I have tried using a foreground dispatch will null for both the IntentFilters and TechList though when a picture is being beamed over and my application is in the foreground I do not intercept it. Things like Contacts however are intercepted.

Does anyone know how to also intercept things like pictures so that I am always grabbing all of the items sent to the phone? I do not even care about the picture, all I care about is the tag.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Please, show us some source code.

Comment: @NFCguy Hi, sorry for being a little cheeky, but you seem to have answered a lot of questions on NFC. Could you have a look at the following. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860223/how-to-intercept-nfc-tag-before-onnewintent-executes

Answer (score -1):

Your #enableForegroundDispatch method is like this?

```
protected final void enableNfcEventDiscover() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    if (nfcAdapter == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Cannot enable discover nfc events, you need set the NfcAdapter first");

    } else {

        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
    }
}
```